# Will minio be suitable for frequently uploads and downloads

Tags: file-upload, data-structures, upload, storage, minio

I am making a website in which there can be frequently uploads of users 
sharing multipart files.
and there will be frequently downloads also.

I am thinking of using minio for this.

For storage needs it will be best but i don't know whether it will be good for frequently downloads also..

Will it be a good for this purpose ??
Or there is other solution for this kind of Problem which is like minio
which will be easier to learn and work with.??